# Jenkins Jobs are not to be seen after network issue

Tags: jenkins

Today morning, we noticed all Putty Jobs running Jenkins were closed due to Network Issue. Once network was up, we re-started Jenkins and we observed that Jenkins Dashboard was not showing ANY jobs. We had around 80 Jobs on the dash board. We are using VM servers for Master/Slave setup. Config.xml is fine. What do we do? how do we get back on track?

Answer (score 0):

All the jenkins jobs are basically xml config files kept in jenkins home.
If your Jenkins is not showing these jobs then it is not using same home directory.

Kindly check jenkins process to see which directory it is pointing to.